# How to do a same day date_range filter in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I have a situation where I have two models, where there is a 1:1 association between them and some method delegation:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :receipt

  delegate :date, to: :receipt, prefix: true
end

class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

so that you can get the date of a receipt by calling `sale_object.receipt_date`.  What I need is a filter in ActiveAdmin on the `Sale` index page where I can select all those sales objects where the associated receipt `date` is in a given range.  So I've added this to the AA filters:

```
filter :receipt_date, as: :date_range
```

This provides a filter which accepts a start and end date, and it works but only if the days given are separated by at least one day.  If I want to filter for all `Sale` objects on a particular day (say by entering in 1-22-2024 for both the "From" and "To" fields) the query looks for sales where the receipt date is both greater than and less than the given date, and so nothing is returned.  I've added a couple of ransackers to the `Sale` class:

```
def self.receipt_date_gteq(date)
  joins(:receipt).where('receipts.date >= ?', date.to_date)
end

def self.receipt_date_lteq(date)
  joins(:receipt).where('receipts.date <= ?', date.to_date + 1.day)
end
```

with the second date filter adding a day to the query thus making it effectively the end of that day instead of the beginning.  This solves the problem with single day filters not working, but for some reason the "From" and "To" fields in the filter don't populate with the entered values.  The query values show up in the URL and also in the "Search Status" box below the filters but they are gone from the filter input itself.  In this organization it is very common for people to make several progressive filters, starting with a given date range and then drilling down from that.  If the values don't populate it will make their job harder and make me a lousy coder.  Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?  How can I rework these filters so that same day filtering works, and the values properly populate in the From/To fields?

Comment: From my understanding `filter :receipt_date, as: :date_range` should produce `gteq` and `lteq` predication but your post suggests you are seeing `gt` and `lt`: *"receipt date is both greater than and less than the given date"*. Maybe the issue is that `receipt` is a date time and you just need appropriate times? What happens if you go with `where(receipts: {date: date.to_date.beginning_of_day..})` and `where(receipts: {date: ..date.to_date.end_of_day})`?

Comment: Also as far as why they don't show up I can't say as it appears that issue should have been fixed a while ago https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4640